# R: Extract Rows from One Data Frame, Based on Column Names Matching Values from Another Data Frame

Tags: r

I would like to know how to extract the values in one column of a data frame **(data frame A)** based on certain column names in data frame A containing the values of multiple columns from another data frame **(data frame B)**.

More specifically. I have two data frames:

**Data frame A** contains combinations of birth defects. Each row is a different combination, and each column is the number of a defect included in that combination.

```r
# Combinations data frame 
combos <- data.frame("combo_no"=c(1:4),
                     "Defect_A" = c(1,1,1,1),
                     "Defect_B" = c(3,2,3,4),
                     "Defect_C" = c(4,4,NA,7),
                     "Defect_D" = c(5,5,NA,8),
                     "Defect_E" = c(6,6,NA,NA))
```

**Data frame B** contains individual cases. The first column has a unique identifier (CASE_ID). The rest of the columns are the numbers of specific birth defects, with “1” for “birth defect present” and “0” for “not present.”

```r
# Cases data set 
set.seed(99)
CASE_ID = c(1001:1005)
case1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)  
case2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)  
case3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)  
case4 = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)  
case5 = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)  
def<-data.frame(rbind(case1, case2, case3, case4, case5))
colnames(def)<- c(1:10)
cases<-cbind(CASE_ID,def)
```

**Desired Output:** I would like to obtain the list of CASE_IDs from data frame A that have a combination of birth defects from data frame B. I’d also like to specify which combination is present. 
Ideally, the output would look as follows:

```r
# Desired Output
output <- data.frame("CASE_ID" = c(1002,1003),
                     "combo_no" = c(3,1))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you mean that each row of the first DB contains the info about which combination of numbers of the second DB compose the combination? As example, "combo_no: 1" is composed of child with 1,3,4,5,6 in the second table?

Comment: yes, combo_no:1 is composed of defects 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6. Child 1 (case_ID: 10001) has this combo. In the full data set, multiple case ids could have this combo.

Comment: answered, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution, long in order to comment it step by step:

```
### my random generated cases DF:
cases
      CASE_ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
case1    1001 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  0
case2    1002 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  0
case3    1003 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0  0
case4    1004 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1  1
case5    1005 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1  0
```

```
### initialize vectors to store found results
found_combos <- vector(); found_patients <- vector();
### open loop on combos rows
for (i in 1:nrow(combos)) {
  ### open empty vector to fill with the numbers that compose the defect
  defect_numbers <- vector()
  ### open loop on column and take the numbers
  for (col in colnames(combos)[2:length(colnames(combos))]) {
    number <- combos[i, col]
    if ( !is.na(number) ) defect_numbers <- append(defect_numbers, number)
  }
  ### sort the vector to avoid mismatch based on order
  defect_numbers <- sort( defect_numbers )
  ### open loop on patients table
  for ( pz in 1:nrow(cases) ) {
    pz_numbers <- sort( which( cases[pz,] == 1 )-1 )
    ### first condition: same length
    if ( length(pz_numbers) == length(defect_numbers) ) {
      ### same condition: exacly same numbers
      if (all(pz_numbers == defect_numbers)) {
        ### append to found results vectors
        found_patients <- append( found_patients, cases[pz,1] )
        found_combos <- append( found_combos, i )
      }
    }
  }
}

output <- data.frame("CASE_ID" = found_patients,
                     "combo_no" = found_combos)

### result:
output
  CASE_ID combo_no
1    1002        2
```

---

**EDITED based on your comment:**

just change the conditions from equals to %in% :

```
### initialize vectors to store found results
found_combos <- vector(); found_patients <- vector();
for (i in 1:nrow(combos)) {
  ### open empty vector to fill with the numbers that compose the defect
  defect_numbers <- vector()
  ### open loop on column and take the numbers
  for (col in colnames(combos)[2:length(colnames(combos))]) {
    number <- combos[i, col]
    if ( !is.na(number) ) defect_numbers <- append(defect_numbers, number)
  }
  ### sort the vector to avoid mismatch based on order
  defect_numbers <- sort( defect_numbers )
  ### open loop on patients table
  for ( pz in 1:nrow(cases) ) {
    pz_numbers <- sort( which( cases[pz,] == 1 )-1 )
    ### only condition: all defect_numbers in combo_numbers vector
    if (all(defect_numbers %in% pz_numbers)) {
      ### append to found results vectors
      found_patients <- append( found_patients, cases[pz,1] )
      found_combos <- append( found_combos, i )
    }
  }
}

output <- data.frame("CASE_ID" = found_patients,
                     "combo_no" = found_combos)
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I change the code so that the combo gets selected even if the patient has more defects than those in the combo? For example, CASE_ID: 1001 contains combo_no:1 (defects 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6), even though it also includes defect 7.

Comment: edited as you requested, please consider accept the answer and upvote

Comment: For some reason, when I try to run the code on the real dataset, I can't get it to work. The table comes up empty. I've checked to make sure the data types are the same

Comment: @LulisNavarro it could be for many reason, if you provide me (editing the question) a real example of your DB (even only an head) I can make it work